# Avoid checkbox clicked when label has been clicked

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a checkbox and label like so. The problem here is I cannot click the `href` due to the whole section works as a single unit. i.e. when I clicked the label it fires the checkbox. So how can I separate or avoid this behavior? i.e. I need to click hyperlink.

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label class="long-text">I accept the Terms & Conditions and the Privacy Policy found
      <a href="#" (click)="goToPrivacyPolicy()">here</a></ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="terms" slot="start"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
```

*UI*

[image]

**Tried this: But no Luck yet?**

*.ts*

```
  goToPrivacyPolicy(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); //or event.preventDefault()
    this.iab.create(environment.privacyPolicy);
  }
```

*html*

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label class="long-text">I accept the Terms & Conditions and the Privacy Policy found
      <a href="#" (click)="goToPrivacyPolicy($event)">here</a></ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="terms" slot="start"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
```

Comment: Try adding `position:relative` to `a` element https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-terms-and-conditions-ytr8eh?file=pages/home/home.ts

Answer (score 1):

**CHECK** [**WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-terms-and-conditions)

```
<ion-item text-wrap>
 <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-2 no-padding no-margin>
      <ion-item no-padding no-margin no-lines>
        <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="agreed"></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-10 no-padding no-margin>
      <ion-item no-padding no-margin no-lines>
        Agree to <a target="_blank" href="http://www.terms-of-service.com">Terms of Service</a> and <a target="_blank" href="http://www.privacy-policy.com">Privacy Policy</a>. found  <a href="#" (click)="goToPrivacyPolicy($event)">here</a>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: No difference. Same behavior like my post.

Comment: Yes, I know this behavior. Actually, it was an accidental use case. i.e. I have developed dynamic checkbox list using `ion-grid` and it doesn't have this behavior. But The current page developed using `<ion-item>`. So it'll take time to redo using the grid. Anyway, I have found a hack for this. I'll put it later. Thanks and +1.